# not found in the dependency injection container

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

at this album-o-rama sample mvc application has one error to load controller and action after add / at the end of the url for EX: http://album-o-rama.phalconphp.com/album/38251/InnerSpeaker/

at the above url have a error: Service 'view' was not found in the dependency injection container

but this url is ok and loaded : http://album-o-rama.phalconphp.com/album/38251/InnerSpeaker

what the reason of the error and how to handel this problem with out redirect?

also at this forum : Page not found: http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2666/not-found-in-the-dependency-injection-container/ ---> have error and redirect to index controller http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2666/not-found-in-the-dependency-injection-container ---> its ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra slash produces a not found action which is not currently handled by that example.
You can use the built-in extra slash remover as explained here http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#dealing-with-extra-trailing-slashes